# What is the preferred way of separating two integers?

Tags: php

I have variables of form like:
`$x = "1-15"`
`$y = "2-18"`
etc.

I need to extract the first and second integer as separate variables.

For example:
if `$x = "1-15"`, return values should be `$z = 1` and `$w = 15`.

I know that It would be possible to do this with regex, but from what I've heard, it should be avoided if possible.

What then would be the "fastest" way of achieving this?

Comment: have you tried `regex`?

Comment: _"but from what I've heard, it should be avoided if possible"_ No - it should just be used appropriately

Comment: Try this: list($z, $w) = explode('-', $x);

Comment: Will they only ever be positive integers? or could you have negative integers as well?

Comment: If it's always going to be dashes, you can just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), but regex will work as well.

Comment: `explode()` if the delimiter is the same, if not you would need regex `[-+*/]` etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure this is the format, you can split the string (assuming it is a string, and not literally what you wrote).

Splitting is done with `explode` in php:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$x = "1-15"; //assuming it is indeed a string
list($z, $w) = explode('-', $x);
```

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš If your strings might have spaces in them, just strip the spaces out before exploding, like this: `list($z,$w)=explode("-",str_replace(' ','',$x));`

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode` is a better option, If you want to go with `regex`, Hope this solution will be okay.

**Regex:** `^\s*(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)\s*$`

> **1.** `^\s*(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)\s*$` This will match `digits - digits` pattern, this will take care of spaces as well.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/787216)

```
<?php

$x = '1-15';
extract(getVariables($x));
echo $z;
echo $w;
function getVariables($x)
{
    preg_match("/^\s*(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)\s*$/", $x,$matches);
    return array("z"=>$matches[1],"w"=>$matches[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! If the spaces will be a problem, I'll use your suggested method.

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš Yes it can be... Lets say if `$x = '1      -15';` then if you do further comparison like `if("1   "=="1")
{
    echo "same";
}` then it will not work..

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to use your snippet, but it seems to only work if the white space is before the `"-"` like:  `$x = '1 -15';`, but if it is it after the dash like:  `$x = '1-   15';` it doesn't work. How could this be fixed?

Comment: I would, but since the "explode" comment answers my question directly, I think It's fair if I don't change my the "correct answer" on something I hadn't mentioned in the question. But, thank you!